# Question about Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

If you go to  https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors    at Behaviors section you will see:

```
  (function ($) {
     Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
     attach: function (context, settings) {
     $('.example', context).click(function () {
     $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
  });
 }
```

};

})(jQuery);

I think 'example' should be the name of a class like:

```
   <p class="example"><?php echo click here?> <?p>
```

so when clicking on "Click here", the toggle will work. Am I right? And also what is 'ul' in $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');?

So if I have :

```
 for($b=1;$b<$number;$b++)
   {  ?>  
      <p class="toggler" style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo "Commentsfor Paragraph $b:" ."<br>" . "<br>" ; ?> </p> 
     <div class="comment"> 
    <?php
      print render($p[$b]); 
      ?>
     </div> <?php  

      }
```

and what I want to hide or show is the in , then can I write:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
       (function ($) {
         Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
         $('.toggler', context).click(function () {
          $(this).next('div').toggle('show');
        });
      }
     };


   })(jQuery);
 </script>
```

or can I mention the class or id of div  in $(this).next('div').toggle('show'); , so that the data in that part will hide or show? I hope I am clear.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a little bit extra, however I won't go into more detail about the solution to your problem because this question was originally about the behavior example.  Keep your other question to get more into the specifics of your custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those examples are not complete working code examples.

They are just to illustrate that in Drupal 6 you did this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = function (context) {
  // Your code goes here.
}
```

And in Drupal 7 you would generally do this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Your code goes here.
  }
};
```

The rest of the code in those examples is not relevant.

However:

1. Yes, it means that if you click an element with the class "example" it will run the code in your click handler. Your example code is buggy though, it should be like this: `<p class="example"><?php echo 'click here'; ?> </p>`
2. The "ul" is referring to an [unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) element. So it will get the next ul from the element you clicked and toggle it.

[EDIT]

To answer your additional question about the example code:

> or can I mention the class or id of div in $(this).next('div').toggle('show'); , so that the data in that part will hide or show?

Yes you can specify any selector you want, for example:

```
$('.comment').toggle('show');
```

Comment: so if I have something like: for($b=1;$b<$number;$b++)
{  ?>  
   <p class="toggler" style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo "Commentsfor Paragraph $b:" ."<br>" . "<br>" ; ?> </p> 
  <div class="comment"> 
<?php
  print render($p[$b]); 
  ?>
 </div> <?php  

 }  since what I want to toggel is the part in <div></div> can I say <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.toggler', context).click(function () {
        $(this).next('div').toggle('show');
      });
    }
  };


})(jQuery);
</script>?

Comment: Please post code in your original question. It's too hard to read in the comment.

Comment: I have also asked a question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136285/jquery-toggle-does-not-work-all-the-times

Comment: I updated my question.@rooby

Comment: so how can I mention the id or class of that div? So that if I have a div inside another div, it works correctly. Because as I have mentioned in my other question that I have mentioned in above, it does not work correctly now. so I thought that if instead of saying div in $(this).next('div').toggle('show');, I could put the id or class of div ,it works correctly. Can you also please look at my other question and see if you can help me. I would really appreciate it. @ rooby

Comment: I already added  part about that at the bottom of this answer. You have a div with the class comment and that last line of code in my answer will toggle that element. Getting deeper into the specifics of your code and requirements is out of scope of this question/answer and should be left for your other question, which specifically relates to your custom code.